# Be notified when node rejects TX from mempool

Tags: doublespend, mempool, nbitcoin

I need to be notified on my C# backend implementing NBitcoin when my node detects a double spend and rejects a TX from its Mempool.
Is there a RPC call or some kind of events that I can register to to receive this kind of notifications?